# Unable to Login to Plask Panel

Tags: windows, authentication

I'm Unable to Login to Plask Control Panel, this issue started few days back, at the time, I was using Plask v11.5.

When I tried to log in, the browser started submit my request but a few minutes after, it would show:

`Error 500, Application error`

I try to run reconfigurator.exe to verify & fix the Plesk installation, everything updated fine but issues still exist today i decided to upgrade to v12 and i upgrade to V12, everything installed fine but login issues persisted.

After update whey i try to login, i'm not getting any error message, but after some time i got mail from the server "alarm level changed. Server health parameter "Services > Plesk CPU usage" changed its status from "green" to "red"."

Here is some log details

```
2014-07-10T22:28:29+05:30 ERR (3): The system cannot find the file specified. (Error code 2) at Unable to connect to pipe \\.\pipe\I_bbe664d5-de53-4079-8e26-fe00fc20aac0

[2014-07-13T12:03:25Z][79736][ERROR][:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\sso\htdocs\base\main_handler s.php(32) error_handler] Script error [8] in C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\sso\htdocs\lib\pear\Net\Sock et.php (340): fwrite(): send of 299 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Please help, Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you
Anu Vasudevan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. No solution is avaliable, only disabling the sso can solve it.

http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/117135

For Plesk for Windows, command is similar:
"%plesk_dir%/bin/sso" --disable